# Create a new AzureAD user and add to distribution list

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, office365, exchangewebservices

I'm running a script to add a new user to Azure AD

```
$AzureADConnection = Connect-AzureAD
$AdminEmail = $AzureADConnection.Account.Id
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName $AdminEmail -ShowProgress $false

$ADUserParameters = @{
    DisplayName         = $DisplayName
    GivenName           = $FirstName
    SurName             = $LastName
    UserPrincipalName   = $UserPrincipalName
    MailNickName        = $MailNickName
    UsageLocation       = $UsageLocation
    CompanyName         = $CompanyName
    JobTitle            = $JobTitle
    Department          = $Department
    PasswordProfile     = $PasswordProfile
    AccountEnabled      = $true
}

$NewAzureADUser = New-AzureADUser @ADUserParameters -ErrorAction Stop
```

The user is created successfully, however, when I run the command to add a user to the Distribution list in the same process, I get an error that the user is not found

```
$dl = "Somegroup@testdomain.com"
Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $dl -Member $UserPrincipalName
```

> Couldn't find object "sdtestuser2@testdomain.com". Please make sure that it was spelled correctly or specify a different
> object.
> + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-DistributionGroupMember], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TimeStamp=8/9/202
> 2 11:55:40 AM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ManagementObjectNotFoundException] D103D115,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.R
> ecipientTasks.AddDistributionGroupMember
> + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com

At the same time, if I run the command after creating a user, then everything works. Can someone please suggest how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

***I tried in my environment and got the same error as below:***

```
$PasswordProfile = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile
$PasswordProfile.Password = "password"
New-AzureADUser -DisplayName "srirukuser" -PasswordProfile $PasswordProfile -UserPrincipalName "sriruk33@XXXXX" -AccountEnabled $true -MailNickName "srirukuser"
$dl = "testgroup@XXXX"
Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $dl -Member "sriruk33@XXXXX"
```

**Response:**

[image]

Please **note** that, the error usually occurs if the creation of Azure Ad user is still in progress when you tried to add it to Distribution list.

**To resolve the error,** you can wait for 2-3 mins before executing **`Add-DistributionGroupMember`** command or you can pause the code by adding **sleep** like below:

```
While (-not (Get-AzureAdUser -ObjectId "$UPNOftheuser")){ 
    #User still isn't fully created, so pause for 3 minutes before trying again
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 180
}
```

When I tried to add the member after few minutes of user creation, **user got** **added successfully to the Distribution list like below:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Creating and adding new users to distribution list in Azure by Shelly3360](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2192510-creating-and-adding-new-users-to-distribution-list-in-azure)

Answer (score 0):

thanks M R Rukmini!
I have slightly modified your script and it turned out what I need

```
$endTime = $(Get-Date).AddMinutes(5)
    write-host "Creating a mailbox, it may take a few minutes..."
    While ((-not(Get-Mailbox -Identity $UserPrincipalName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue )) -and ( $endTime -gt $(Get-Date))){ 
        
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
        write-host "checking..." 
    }
    write-host "User mailbox has been created"
```